# entropy changes in common processes?

Tags: entropy

Can you point me please to a reference that will explain what the entropy undergoes (increase, decrease, etc) in common thermodynamic cycle processes, like adiabatic, isobaric, isochoric, etc?

Comment: A common thermodynamics textbook?

Comment: Do you really mean cycles?  In a thermodynamic cycle, the entropy of the working fluid does not change, because entropy is a function of state (and in a cycle, you return to the original state).

Answer (score 0):

You can watch these two videos, they will give you the right intuition to think about some thermodynamic processes.

1. https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/entropy-chemistry-sal/v/work-done-by-isothermic-process
2. https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/entropy-chemistry-sal/v/carnot-cycle-and-carnot-engine

If you like you can select and see the videos you want from the thermodynamic section of the site:
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry

hope it will help...If you want reference to any article or book except videos then please write.